# How to switch python version permanently, without "activating" environments?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda

I would like to be able to switch Python version permanently, in OS-wide manner and reboot tolerant, is it possible?

I don't want to use usual `activate` approach, which shows environment in command line prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you can simply install a new version of anaconda and add it to the `PATH` *before* the old version (and any other python versions). Windows will then find this version of python first, and it will thus be your "OS-wise" python installation.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I think you just have to change your `PATH` environment variable and add the path to your favorite python.

I think you don't need to reboot your machine but you may have to restart your command line console (cmd.exe) to take it into account